# re arraging XML file with 2 linear layouts inside

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have the following XML file -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="13dp"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_product_title"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_description_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/products_row_item_product_description" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/very_light_grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/products_row_item_price_text"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_likes"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_heart_image_view"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/like_heart" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which looks like this - (quite a mess, that's why I am here :) )

[image]

My goal is to make the XML look like this -

[image]

So I need to change the following issues -

1) price tag needs to be in the start and like count & image should be at the end. Tried to put both gravity & layout_gravity to them at end/start - nothing changes. why ?

2) Image needs to be consistent side, no matter what image I get. How do I make sure the image will always stay the same?

3) Bottom linear layout is way too big. I need to shrink it down - tried to play around with it's height and got a big mess.

4) any other noticeable differences will be appreciated

Comment: Something like this can be arranged more easily in a `RelativeLayout` than `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @dguy I feel like I got it quite okay but it just needs a few tweaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `RelativeLayout`. Here is simple layout to start off:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="13dp"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Special | Simple Product Title Very Very Long"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainImageView1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="By Unreliable Vendor"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTextView1"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView2"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTextView2"
        android:background="#1BB140"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="$200.00"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#F8F0F0"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/mainImageView2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mainImageView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Simple Product Layout]